# How to emit CSS chunk for styles from HTMLWebpackPlugin chunk?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, mini-css-extract-plugin

I'm trying to use CSS modules for html, produced by html-webpack-plugin.

[Code to reproduce error](https://github.com/ogonkov/nunjucks-loader/tree/add_examples/examples/isomorphic)

**src/index.ejs**

```
<div class="<%= require('./item.css').foo %>"></div>
```

**src/styles.css**

```css
.foo {
  color: red
}
```

This code, bundled with following config is somehow working (css modules hashed class names find their way to generated `index.html`):

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            onlyLocals: true,
                            modules: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.ejs'
        })
    ]
};
```

But the problem is that CSS chunk is not get emmited.

```
% npm run build -- --mode production

> simple-nunjucks-loader-example-isomporphic@1.0.0 build /Users/user/Projects/nunjucks-loader/examples/isomorphic
> webpack "--mode" "production"

Hash: 5edf5687d32d114e6469
Version: webpack 4.41.5
Time: 526ms
Built at: 01/02/2020 10:51:04 PM
     Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.html   98 bytes          [emitted]  
   main.js  930 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] ./src/index.js 1.43 KiB {0} [built]
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.ejs 283 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
    [4] ./src/item.css 68 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
```

When i add `mini-css-extract-plugin` to config to get CSS chunks emmited, it throws error:

**webpack.config.js**

```
@@ -1,5 +1,4 @@
 const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
+const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

 module.exports = {
     module: {
@@ -23,9 +22,6 @@ module.exports = {
             {
                 test: /\.css$/,
                 use: [
+                    {
+                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
+                    },
                     {
                         loader: 'css-loader',
                         options: {
@@ -40,11 +36,7 @@ module.exports = {

     plugins: [
         new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
+            template: 'src/index.ejs',
+        }),
+        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
-            template: 'src/index.ejs'
-        })
     ]
 };
```

```
% npm run build -- --mode production

> simple-nunjucks-loader-example-isomporphic@1.0.0 build /Users/user/Projects/nunjucks-loader/examples/isomorphic
> webpack "--mode" "production"

/Users/user/Projects/nunjucks-loader/examples/isomorphic/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:16
    throw new Error('Callback was already called.');
    ^

Error: Callback was already called.
    at throwError (/Users/user/Projects/nunjucks-loader/examples/isomorphic/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:16:11)
    at /Users/user/Projects/nunjucks-loader/examples/isomorphic/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! simple-nunjucks-loader-example-isomporphic@1.0.0 build: `webpack "--mode" "production"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the simple-nunjucks-loader-example-isomporphic@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2020-01-02T19_53_48_953Z-debug.log
```

When loading same template by importing it from JS file, everything works as expected.

**UPDATE**. Temporary solution is to have *2* rulesets, one for template (w/out `mini-css-extract-plugin` and `onlyLocals`), and one for js, with regular set of rules, and duplicate same style import in JS.

It's not ideal, but produce html + css modules.

```js
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                oneOf: [
                    {
                        issuer: /\.ejs$/,
                        use: [{
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                onlyLocals: true,
                                modules: true
                            }
                        }]
                    },

                    {
                        issuer: /\.js$/,
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                            },
                            {
                                loader: 'css-loader',
                                options: {
                                    modules: true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

```js
import './item.css';
```

Comment: Hm, I got here by googling same error, could it be that there is a bug in a recent `mini-css-extract-plugin` release `v0.9.0`? (considering the question was pasted just a week ago)

Comment: Related discussion: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/489

Comment: @ArturKlesun seems like "callback" error was first introduced in 0.8.1, at 0.8.0 there is another error thrown.

Comment: I have post console output to GitHub issue above.

Comment: Adds temporary hack to get something that looks like what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to deal with "Callback was already called" error by using [file-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader) + [extract-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-loader) instead of `mini-css-extract-plugin`:

```js
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.html?$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
            attrs: ['link:href', 'img:src']
        },
    }],
});
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.css(\?.*)?$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: 'css/[name].[contenthash].[ext]',
        },
    }, 'extract-loader', 'css-loader'],
});
```

Though my case was a bit different: my entry point was a plain `html` file with `<link href="..."/>` references, not `ejs`, and I sadly did not manage to make it work with your [gist](https://gist.github.com/ogonkov/2e23941414d6f0b3d5328bd80cba5674) due to lack of knowledge of `ejs`. But I hope my solution may be of help.

Comment: It emits CSS, but on the other hand it returns file path, instead of module ids, that i really need to wire file and template.